# When an option tag is selected, how do you navigate to another page and then run a jQuery function automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, hyperlink

I am creating a way-finding app using HTML5, jQuery and Javascript. There are 3 total html pages and each page has a different legend. In this app I have buttons that call a jQuery click function to display stars on the map above the location you have selected. Each button has an id and the buttons work how I want them to work. The problem is that I want to add a drop down list that will provide the same functionality as the buttons on the legend. So basically what I want to be able to do is select a section from the drop down list and then jump to the page that has that section and have the stars already displayed for the selected section. IE: If I select Restrooms, I want to be able to jump the ground floor and have stars displayed over the restrooms. Is this possible to do? I tried using a Javascript function to make the URL navigate to the value of the select list option I wanted but that didn't make the stars show up. I am fairly new to Javascript and jQuery so please help. Thanks! Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form method="get" name="form1" action="">  
 <select name="locations" onchange="gotoSection(this.form)">
      <option selected>Please pick a Section</option>
      <option disabled>---Ground Floor---</option>
      <option value="grdFloor.html#mc" >Mayor's Commision on Literacy</option>
      <option value="grdFloor.html#ch">Children's</option>
      <option value="grdFloor.html#sr">Story Book Room</option>
      <option value="grdFloor.html#eo">Extensions Office</option>
      <option value="grdFloor.html#ma">Montgomery Auditorium</option>
      <option value="grdFloor.html#restRm">Restrooms</option>     
  </select>
</form>

<div id="restRm" class="legend">
    <a href="#restRm" ><img src="floorMaps/restBTN.png"/></a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.legend, .arrows').show('slow');                     
   $('.stars').hide();
       $('#restRm').click(function(){
    $('.stars:not(#restStar1, #restStar2)').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#restStar1, #restStar2').toggle('pulsate');
   }); //end restroom
```

Javascript:

```
function gotoSection(form) { 

    var newIndex = form.locations.selectedIndex; 
    if ( newIndex == 0 ) { 
        alert( "Please select a Section!" ); 

    } else { 
        cururl = form.locations.options[ newIndex ].value; 
        window.location.assign( 'http://libwww3.freelibrary.org/maps/central/' + cururl ); 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select name="locations" onchange="gotoSection(this.value)">

function gotoSection(cururl) { 
    window.location.assign( 'http://libwww3.freelibrary.org/maps/central/' + cururl ); 
}
```

EDIT:
Maybe i should read the entire question before i answer, i thought the problem was that your navigation didn't work, i apologize.

But as to the question about the stars, if i understand your question and example code correctly, you're navigating within the same page, just with diferent #hash tags. And if thats the case, your document.ready won't run.
Instead you can make a function that triggers the stars and call that from your gotoSection method, after you've assigned the new url.

Comment: I see thanks for the advice, I'll try out a function to trigger the stars.

Comment: Okay so I have modified the gotoSection Javascript Function. What I want to know is if there is anyway I can redirect a page to a different URL and then trigger the stars automatically when I reach that page?

Comment: Include the method that renders the stars on the page you are linking to, and run it when the page is loaded.

Comment: You can do it by running this code: jQuery(function() {
   ShowStars();
});

Comment: I have actually scrapped the whole different URL navigation and made all 3 maps on the same website. That way I could have one function and just pass in the variables I wanted into the function which would show the floor that you selected and hide the other ones. Thanks for all your help, I appreciate it.